# Main Window DataContext StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I know this might sound crazy, but for the sake of my understanding, how would you explain that setting `Window.DataContext` to `MainWindow` results in this error:

> "Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown."

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindow />
  </Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a window is initialized, the XAML is inflated in to real objects.  Those real objects have their constructors called, which initializes them.

This line actually creates a *new* instance of `MainWindow`, instead of returning the existing instance:

```
<local:MainWindow />
```

So your XAML creates a new window, which sets the `DataContext` to a new window, which sets its `DataContext` to a new window, which sets its `DataContext` to a new window, which sets its `DataContext` to a new window, which sets its `DataContext` to a new window, which sets its `DataContext` to a new window, which sets its `DataContext` to a new window, which sets its `DataContext` to a new window, which sets its `DataContext` to a new window, which sets its `DataContext` to a new window, which sets its `DataContext` to a new window, which sets its `DataContext` to a new window,

and so on, until the whole things crashes and burns.

What you *probably* meant to do, is *this*:

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
</Window>
```

Which sets the `DataContext` to the current *instance* of the window, not a new window.